# How can I request a status update on an apple bug report?

Tags: bug

So I was reading the [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/resources/bug-reporting.html) for Apple's [bug reporter site](http://bugreport.apple.com) and I came across this:

```
To request a status on an existing issue, please update your report directly via the
Apple Bug Reporter requesting a status update and we will provide you with any
available information.
```

I got curious about this, and I went back to bugreport.apple.com to look at one of my pending bug reports and I didn't see any way of explicitly asking for a `status update`. I feel that I'm missing something obvious, because I expect the FAQ to be correct, but so far I haven't got the faintest. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as posting new details on your bug with a sentence requesting a status update. There is no dedicated button to do this. From personal experience I doubt you'll get any helpful information though. Many things in Radar live there for years…